# UIActivityView not animating

Tags: objective-c, user-interface

I have a button on the iPhone interface that performs a function. The function is this:

```
-(IBAction)courses:(id)sender {
[loading startAnimating];
[connection getCourses];
[outlet setText:connection.lastResponseData];
}
```

My problem is that the animation only starts after the `[outlet setText:connection.lastResponseData`. How can I get the loading to start animating before that?

Thanks.

Comment: If you are using CA to handle the animations, then it shouldn't be blocking the main thread, which is probably what you're doing anyhow...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `getCourses` is blocking the main thread; any animations you start will be deleted until after `courses:` returns. Modify your code to use a background thread:

```
-(IBAction)courses:(id)sender {
[loading startAnimating];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        [connection getCourses];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [outlet setText:connection.lastResponseData];       
            [loading stopAnimating];
        });
    });
}
```

This will put your blocking network access in a system-provided background GCD queue, which wraps a background thread.

Comment: That's super cool except that recalls our old good goto buddy :) Could you please guide me a little to understand better from where the animations are deleted ?

Comment: How do I stop the animation after the [outlet setText] part?

Comment: Just call `stopAnimating` to stop the animation; I'll amend my answer.

Comment: With regards to this being reminiscent of `goto` statements, this is actually a new technology Apple introduced into iOS 4 where you can dispatch blocks of code (treated as Objective-C objects at runtime, in fact) to queues that wrap POSIX threads. This easily allows you to write simple multithreaded code; it's become [Apple's recommended approach to concurrent programming](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/ConcurrencyandApplicationDesign/ConcurrencyandApplicationDesign.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH100-SW8).

Comment: @Ash Furrow With such strong arguments i can only thank you for contributing, it surely means i'll need to go again through the concurrent programming section.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that your connection blocks the main thread, which is also responsible for the UI. Try to interact with UI while the `connection` is started but not finished, if it doesn't respond - make the connection running in another thread.

---

For example, asynchronous [NSURLConnection](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html) will not block your UI.

Comment: I can't use the UI while the connection is processing. How would I put the connection on another thread?

Comment: Ok. I am still not quite sure how to put it on another thread

Comment: The answer update won't put your code in a different thread, but will use an asynchronous access technique with the main thread. @A-Live is talking about changing the code in the `getCourses` method.

Comment: @Ash Furrow i'm pretty confident NSURLConnection will put the stuff in the background thread, please don't tell me it completely executes on the main, don't ruin my world.

Comment: Haha - yes, luckily `NSURLConnection` (even the synchronous methods) work on their own, special thread. I just meant the callbacks for `NSURLConnectionDelegate` execute on the main thread.

Comment: @Ash Furrow well, that's only natural, thank you for the update.